# How to check file size of each file before uploading multiple files in ajaxtoolkit ajaxfileupload control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<cc1:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1"  AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"
runat="server" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4"  OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" 
         />
```

Code behind file

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.FileSize > 10)
        {
            string filePath = e.FileName;
            AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(filePath));
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

I want to check that all the files size should not exceed a particular value before the files upload event.

Comment: Your current code checks the size of the file after it has been uploaded.  If you need something to be checked before upload, I'd suggest a third-party tool like PlUpload.

Comment: I want to use AjaxToolkit control, is there any way to check the file size on client side.

Comment: Not with the AjaxFileUpload control.  `AsyncFileUpload` has `OnClientUploadStarted` that can call a JS function that you could use to check the file size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way:

Server side:

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string savePath = MapPath("~/Images/" + e.FileName);
        // dont save file & return if condition not matched.
        if (e.FileSize > 72000) // use same condition in client side code
        {
            return;
        }
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)    
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

and on client side:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var filesize = args.get_fileSize();
        var fileId = args.get_fileId();

        var status = document.getElementById('AjaxFileUpload1_FileItemStatus_' + fileId);
        var container = document.getElementById('AjaxFileUpload1_FileInfoContainer_' + fileId);


        if (filesize > 72000) { // same condition used for server side
            document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = "error";
            if (status.innerText) {
                status.innerText = " (Error)";
            }
            if (status.textContent) {
                status.textContent = " (Error)";
            }
            container.style.color = 'Red';
        }
    }
</script>

<cc1:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1"  AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg" runat="server" MaximumNumberOfFiles="4"  OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="UploadComplete" />
```

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 1):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".ajax__fileupload_dropzone").bind("drop", function () {
            checkfilesize();
    });
    $(".ajax__fileupload_queueContainer").bind("click", function () {       
            checkfilesize();
    });  
    $(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").bind("mouseenter", function () {
            checkfilesize();
    });

    function checkfilesize() {
        var total_filesize_num = 0;
        var myElements = $(".filesize");
        if (myElements.length == 0) {
            $(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").css("visibility", "hidden");
            return;
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {              
            var filesize = myElements.eq(i).html(); //$(".filesize").html();     
            total_filesize_num = total_filesize_num + filesize_tonum(filesize);
        }
        if (total_filesize_num > 5) {
            $(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").css("visibility", "hidden");
            alert('Maximum file size is 5MB only! Please select another one.');
            return;
        } else {
            $(".ajax__fileupload_uploadbutton").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
    }
    function countsumfilesize() {
        var sumfilesize = 0;
        var myElements = $(".filesize");
        for (var i = 0; i < myElements.length; i++) {
            alert(myElements.eq(i).html());
        }
    }
    function filesize_tonum(filesize) {
        var filesize_num = 0;
        if (filesize.indexOf("kb") > 0) {
            var space = filesize.lastIndexOf(" ");
            filesize_num = parseFloat("0." + filesize.substr(0, filesize.length - space + 1));
        }
        else if (filesize.indexOf("MB") > 0) {
            var space = filesize.lastIndexOf(" ");
            filesize_num = parseFloat(filesize.substr(0, filesize.length - space + 1));
        }    
        return filesize_num;
    }

    </script>

<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUploadImage" runat="server" OnClientUploadComplete="uploadComplete" MaximumNumberOfFiles="1" AllowedFileTypes="gif,png,jpg,jpeg" onchange="checkfilesize(); return false;" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See the code below:

```
public void afuUpload_UploadedComplete(object sender, AsyncFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {
     try
     {
       string savePath = MapPath("~/Uploads/" + Path.GetFileName(e.filename));
       if (int.Parse(e.filesize) > 3000000)
       {
          return;
       }
       afuUpload.SaveAs(savePath);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
        throw ex;
     }}
```

Comment: The code above is not saving the file, if file length is greater than 3000000 but it outputs as if the files are uploaded no error is thrown in this case, can you please tell me how to display error in output page as currently it is showing that files are uploaded.

Comment: @bhanu sorry did'nt get you, could you please make the picture more clear

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to prevent the file is uploaded to the server. In the proposed solution, when the flow code has reached `afuUpload_UploadedComplete`, the file was uploaded to server, but has not yet been recorded in the path you specify. For example, if the limit is 20 megabytes and the selected file is 22 megabytes, when the code reaches `afuUpload_UploadedComplete`, 22 Megabytes already been uploaded to the server.

The solution sought is that the validation is done on the client side (JavaScript) and that prevents the code arrives to `CodeBehind` on the server.

In my case, I tried to `OnClientUploadComplete` generating an exception when the file size limit is exceeded, but it did not work and the code is still reaching the `CodeBehind`. The other problem is that when the exception occurs, the JavaScript function `OnClientUploadError` is not firing  to intercept the exception generated in `OnClientUploadComplete` function.

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
  [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Create(string Album, Photo photo, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files, DateTime? datec, string NewAlbum = null)
  {
  .....

     foreach (var file in files)
            {
                decimal sum = file.ContentLength / 1048;
                if (sum > 4000)
                {
                    errorlist2 += "Sorry " + file.FileName + " has exceeded its file limit off 4 MB  <br/>";


                }

            }

   if (errorlist2 != "")
                {
                    ViewBag.Error = errorlist2;
                    return View(photo);
                }

  // we dont want put the message in the loop it will come out on first max limit , rather find all files in excess, then we can pass the message 
  //also make sure your web config is set  for a limit on max size 

//using the normal html multi uploaded

// <input type="file" name="files" id="files" required multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg, .png, .gif" size="4" />
```