# Curious behaviour of the ClearError() method in Application_Error()?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I attempted to answer this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20580082/cannot-redirect-from-application-error-even-after-clearing-the-error) earlier today and I came across something I couldn't explain, so this is more out of curiosity than necessity.

If you have this code in the Global.asax file:

```
protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpContext.Current.ClearError();
   Response.Redirect("CustomErrors.aspx", false);
   Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
}
```

and then raise an exception in a the `Page_Load()` method what ends up happening is the `Application_Error` gets called twice and then raises this exception:

> Cannot redirect after HTTP headers have been sent.

Raising the same exception within a button click event, results in the `Application_Error` being called once and the redirect correctly occurring.

From my investigations it turns out if you remove `HttpContext.Current.ClearError()` then everything works fine from both `Page_Load()` and the button click.

What I find curious is why does this behaviour only happen from `Page_Load()`? With the button click `Page_Load()` is called before it in the event cycle so I why does it work later down the cycle? Is there some other event that needs to occur after `Page_Load()`? Or is it just better to not attempt to clear the errors in this (`Application_Error`) method?